Unable to access public GitHub repo via its API endpoint when submitting request through FastAPI
I am trying to write a FastAPI mirror to return publicly available GitHub repos for download on a local machine that cannot see the wider internet. However, when I poke the endpoint I've written, I receive a "Bad credentials" response from GitHub.
Interestingly, when I make the same request via Python in the terminal on the same device I'm running the FastAPI endpoint on, the request is approved and I get the response containing the package assets and download URLs that I need.
Why is my request via Python in the terminal approved and not that via FastAPI, even though both originate from the same device? In both cases, I have not supplied any credentials, as GitHub's API endpoints for public releases are supposed to be accessible without the need for authentication (relevant GitHub REST API docs section here).
The code I'm using for reference:
"""
API endpoint in question
"""

import requests
from fastapi import APIRouter, Response

windows_terminal = APIRouter(prefix="/microsoft/terminal")

@windows_terminal.get("/releases/latest", response_class=Response)
def get_latest_windows_terminal_release():
    url = "https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/terminal/releases/latest"
    response = requests.get(url)

    return Response(
        content=response.content,
        status_code=response.status_code,
        headers=response.headers,
    )

The above endpoint returns a "Bad credentials" response when run like that. However, when I provide a GitHub personal access token in the header, it returns the package releases data just fine.
"""
From Python in the terminal on the same device
"""

$ python
$ import requests
$ url = "https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/terminal/releases/latest"
$ response = requests.get(url)
$ print(response.text)

The command line option succeeds at returning the JSON blob with info on the latest release of the package I need, even when I don't provide it with a GitHub token.
And here are the headers for the response and request for the API endpoint I wrote when I get the "Bad credentials" response:
# Response Headers
access-control-allow-origin *
access-control-expose-headers   ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Used, X-RateLimit-Resource, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, X-GitHub-SSO, X-GitHub-Request-Id, Deprecation, Sunset
content-length  95
content-security-policy default-src 'none'
content-type    application/json; charset=utf-8
date    Wed, 16 Oct 2024 09:26:30 GMT, Wed, 16 Oct 2024 09:26:30 GMT
referrer-policy origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
server  uvicorn, github.com
strict-transport-security   max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
vary    Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With
x-content-type-options  nosniff
x-frame-options deny
x-github-media-type github.v3; format=json
x-github-request-id C62C:3C7F8A:20BE68E:230F16B:670F86C6
x-ratelimit-limit   60
x-ratelimit-remaining   59
x-ratelimit-reset   1729074390
x-ratelimit-resource    core
x-ratelimit-used    1
x-xss-protection    0


# Request Headers
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-GB,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
DNT 1
Host    ######## (omitted)
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests   1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0


How are you using the windows_terminal router? Are you sure that it's the requests call that is generating the error? What is the stack trace?

Hi, thanks for getting back to me! Apologies, I'm not sure what information you need when you ask me how I'm using the router. It is a server on our local network that client machines without access to the wider internet can poke to download files needed to run their daily tasks. * I'm pretty sure it's the requests that is generating the error, as the response content it returns is completely different. * Additionally, when I provide a GitHub personal access token in the request, it goes through just fine.

On a side note, I would suggest having a look at this answer on how to properly perform HTTP requests within a FastAPI application.

@Chris, thanks for providing the additional reading!
